# Focus issue with ubuntu /unity

Tags: java, linux, swing, ubuntu

I am trying to change the focus of a windows/frame with a shortcut key in Swing.The problem is,when the focus changes,the window that has the focus doesn't move to the top,it gets the focus but stays behind the unfocused window.I get the focus with `Frame.requestFocus();`.Is there any other method I could use for focusing?

Comment: Do you think setVisible(true) would work?  Generally when called for the first time this activates a window.  Unsure if it will have the same effect here.  *public* *void* setVisible(*boolean* b)

Comment: does `frame.toFront()` works?

Comment: Please do try [requestFocusInWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow()) for Swing, though this method is related to JComponent, but it can work on `JFrame`, since it inherits methods from Component class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Frame.toFront();`

Java doc reference: [toFront](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toFront%28%29)